# why is my ajax script reloading my page

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

I am using ajax to submit a form. Well the script I am using is just to test the form where some plain text is echoed in `processform.php`. However when I click on the submit button, nothing gets alert and the page gets reloaded.

isnt that `return false` supposed to prevent from it. And when I delete the ajax part, every thing goes well.

Where am i doing it wrong?

```
$("#submit").click(function(){
      $("#sidebar .message").show();
      $(".sidebar-content").hide();

      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "processform.php",
        data: { name: "John", location: "Boston" }
      }).done(function( msg ) {
        alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
      });

      return false;
    });
```

Comment: Are you preventing the default action of your submit button?

Comment: try `e.preventDefault();`

Comment: ya I tried it as Ruben Infante recommended it in one of the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the element `#submit` is a button or input with `type="submit"`, it will likely trigger a default behavior to send data to whatever the form action happens to be.

You can either change the type to be `type="button"` which does not have a default behavior of submitting data or use [event.preventDefault()](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/) in your click handler to block the default behavior.

```
$("#submit").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    ...
});
```

If you want your alert to trigger when your ajax request is successful, you can use the `success` option instead of `.done()`.

```
$("#submit").click(function () {
    $("#sidebar .message").show();
    $(".sidebar-content").hide();

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "processform.php",
        data: {
            name: "John",
            location: "Boston"
        },
        success: function(msg) {
            alert("Data Saved: " + msg);
        },
        error: function() {
            alert("Error occurred");
        }
    });

    return false;
});
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fhSL2/)

Comment: ya.. I had no idea about the `e.preventDefault();`. Thanks .. I am modifying my code

Comment: But the data from the `processform.php` isnt getting alerted .

Answer (score 2):

The simple solution: change your submit button to type="button" instead of "submit".